# Internal link to a headline by it's number in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I'm using [dynamic headline numbering](https://orgmode.org/manual/Dynamic-Headline-Numbering.html) in my org file and I want to use those numbers as a internal link targets. For example within a org file structured like this:

```
* 1 section
** 1.1 subsection
```

I can use [internal link](https://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-Links.html) like [[subsection]] to create a link to "1.1 subsection" headline. How can I use something like [[1.1]] which uses just headline number as a target of link to that headline.

Comment: Could you add a bit more info, from the links you provide, to make the question more self-contained. Ideally readers shouldn't have to follow links to be able to understand what you're asking. Thx.

Comment: You cannot: headline numbering is done by overlays. They are not contained in the buffer at all, they are calculated dynamically and only exist while the buffer is open (and the mode is turned on). If you look at the file on disk, there are no numbers. Links have to have a physical anchor to go to.